# Handling cache in HTTP 1.0 requests

Tags: http

I would like my web page to expire after 24 hours in a 1.0 HTTP request. I've been trying different combinations of the following headers, but nothing seems to work:

```
If-Modified-Since
Last-Modified
Expires
Cache-Control
Pragma
```

For example:

```
Expires: Wed, 9 Jan 2014 12:31:00 GMT
```

Should last until tomorrow, right? I don't know why, but my client does not respect that.

Comment: Perhaps he was raised badly? Youngsters nowadays. ;) More seriously: what's your client?

Comment: My client is a WAP browser embedded inside a Point-of-sale device. The documentation is poor and I don't have anyone to help me :(